# malloc( ): memory corruption (fast) error C++

Tags: c++, stack, malloc, glibc, capacity

I'm working in C++.  I'm working on a method to change the maximum capacity of a stack and I'm confused about an error I'm getting.  Below is my method.

```
void Stack::setCapacity(unsigned newCapacity){
if(newCapacity< this->getSize()){
    throw StackException("setCapacity()", 
    "the size is larger than the desired capacity");
} else {
    if(newCapacity != myCapacity){
        Item * tempArray = new Item[newCapacity];
        if(newCapacity < myCapacity){
            for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity;i++){
                tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
            }
        } else if (newCapacity > myCapacity) {
            for(unsigned i=0; i<myCapacity; i++){
                tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity; i++){
            myArray[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
        delete tempArray;
    }
    myCapacity = newCapacity;
} 
}
```

I have also written a test method to test that my setCapacity( ) method works.

```
void StackTester::setCapacityTest() {
cout << "- setCapacity... " << flush;

// empty stack
Stack st7(5);
assert(st7.getSize() == 0);
assert(st7.getCapacity() == 5);
st7.setCapacity(7);
assert(st7.getCapacity() == 7);
cout << " 1 " << flush;

// partially filled stack - larger capacity
Stack st8(5);
assert(st8.getCapacity() == 5);
st8.push(3);
st8.push(4);
st8.setCapacity(7);
assert(st8.getCapacity() == 7);
assert(st8.getTop() == 4);
st8.pop();
assert(st8.getTop() == 3);
cout << " 2 " << flush;

// size larger than new capacity
try{
Stack st9(3);
st9.push(7);
st9.push(4);
st9.push(11);
assert(st9.getSize() == 3);
st9.setCapacity(2);
cerr << "setCapacity's new capacity is larger than the size";
exit(1);
} catch(StackException& se){
    cout << " 3 " << flush;
}

// partially filled stack - smaller capacity
Stack st10(5);
assert(st10.getCapacity() == 5);
st10.push(1);
st10.setCapacity(2);
assert(st10.getCapacity() == 2);
assert(st10.getTop() == 1);
cout << " 4 " << flush;

// fully filled stack - larger capacity
Stack st11(2);
assert(st11.getCapacity() == 2);
st11.push(3);
st11.push(7);
assert(st11.getTop() == 7);
st11.setCapacity(3);
assert(st11.getCapacity() == 3);
cout << " 5 " << flush;

cout << " Passed!" << endl;
}
```

When I run each section of the test individually by commenting out the rest, everything works fine.  Each section of the test passes.  However, when I combine the sections and try to run the entire test, I get the following error:

*** glibc detected ** * /home/.../StackProject: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000001e86030 ***

Using the debugger, I've narrowed down the problem to the creation of myArray in the Stack.  For example, after successfully running " 1 " in my test, the creation of myArray in st8(5) in " 2 " causes the program to crash.

My main source of confusion is due to the fact that each section passes individually but they do not pass collectively.  I'm not sure what to do about that.  Is my method written wrong?  If so, how should I correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: what the heck is going on in `setCapacity`? Can you post your class deifnition for Stack?

Comment: Why is malloc in the title and not in the code. What happened to the second code snippet wrt indentation

Comment: `Stack::setCapacity` does nothing

Comment: @EdHeal not true! It leaks memory. That is something.

Comment: @Barry - granted and wastes time

Comment: You need to explain why you create `tempArray`. What exactly changes in your program after you `delete` it (which should be `delete[]` as pointed out in an answer)?

Comment: setCapacity changes the maximum size allowable in a stack without causing a stack overflow.  My constructor for Stack is as follows: `Stack::Stack(unsigned size) {
 if(!(size>0)){
  throw StackException("Stack()", "invalid parameter");
 } else {
  myTop = 0;
  myCapacity = size;
  myArray = new Item[size];
 }
} `  I created tempArray because I needed to create a new array to put my elements in.  myArray has the original capacity whereas tempArray has the new capacity.

Comment: @TheFaceOfBoe - you create the array. fill it an d throw(?) it away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the following problems in `setCapacity`, in the following block of code:

```
  if(newCapacity != myCapacity){
     Item * tempArray = new Item[newCapacity];
     if(newCapacity < myCapacity){
        for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity;i++){
           tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
        }
     } else if (newCapacity > myCapacity) {
        for(unsigned i=0; i<myCapacity; i++){
           tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
        }
     }

     // When newCapacity > myCapacity, myArray does not
     // have enough space for this loop.
     // Say myCapacity = 5 and newCapacity = 7
     // Accessing myArray[5] and myArray[6] is a problem.

     for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity; i++){
        myArray[i] = tempArray[i];
     }

     // You are deleting the newly allocated array, even though you are using
     // the wrong delete operator.
     // myArray still points to the old allocated memory.
     delete tempArray;
  }
```

What you need is:

```
  if(newCapacity != myCapacity){
     Item * tempArray = new Item[newCapacity];
     if(newCapacity < myCapacity){
        for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity;i++){
           tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
        }
     } else if (newCapacity > myCapacity) {
        for(unsigned i=0; i<myCapacity; i++){
           tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
        }
     }

     // Need to delete the old array and keep the new array.

     Item* oldArray = myArray;
     myArray = tempArray;

     // Use the array delete operator, not the simple delete operator.
     delete [] oldArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
delete tempArray;
```

But it's an array, so you have to do:

```
delete [] tempArray;
```

(although I have no idea what this function is doing or why... )